# determine this integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Evaluate

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_6^n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} dx.$$

Here is my attempt:

We will appeal to the DCT. First note that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x.$$

Then we can define $f_n:= (1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} $ and it is pretty clear to see that

$$f_n \rightarrow \chi_{[6,\infty)}e^{-x}$$

a.e., then the integrable function $g$ can be defined as $g(x)=\chi_{[0,\infty)} e^{-x}$ and we clearly have that $g(x)$ is an upper bound for the $f_n$ thus by the DCT, the given integral converges to the integral of $\chi_{[6,\infty)}e^{-x}$, that is,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_6^n(1+\frac{x}{n})^n e^{-2x} dx  = \int \chi_{[6,\infty)} e^{-x} dx =\int_6^\infty e^{-x} dx$$

and the RHS here is just $e^{-6}$.

Comment: Yes. I think I agree with you. You should make the question a bit clearer, but I gather you're after a yes/no verification

Comment: Yes, just wanna know if all my steps are justified correctly.

Comment: You should appeal to the fact that $(1+x/n)^n\to e^x$ monotonically for all positive $x$ to justify $e^x$ dominating $(1+x/n)^n$

Comment: And really, you are integrating $f_n:=(1+x/n)^ne^{-2x}\cdot\chi_{[6,n)}$ over all of $\Bbb R$ so you should appeal to the fact that the functions involved are nonnegative to show that $e^{-x}\chi_{[6,\infty)}$ dominates all the $f_n$ - if the functions were nastier, the presence of $\chi_{[6,n)}$ being variable could make things difficult